# Simple reference variable assignment causing segfault in global pointer to object?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, global-variables, pass-by-reference

I'm getting a segfault on line 15 of my .cpp file. I'm not sure why. Various code snippets:
explosionhandler.h:

```
    class explosionhandler {
        public:
    struct explosion {
    ...
    };
    vector<struct explosion> explosions;
    struct explosion_type {
    ...
    };
    vector<struct explosion_type> type;
    int num_types;

    explosionhandler();
    ~explosionhandler();
    void registerexplosion(int& ttype,ALLEGRO_BITMAP*& b,int seq, float a, float m,float e);

    void createexplosion(int ttype,float x,float y);
    void drawexplosions(ALLEGRO_BITMAP* screen);

    void gettype(explosion_type& a,ALLEGRO_BITMAP*& b,int& nseq, float& aa, float& ee, float& mm);


        };#endif
```

explosionhandler.cpp:

```
    explosionhandler::explosionhandler()
    {
        num_types=0;
    }
    void explosionhandler::registerexplosion(int& ttype,ALLEGRO_BITMAP*& b,int seq, float a, float m,float e)
    {
        explosion_type n;
        ....
        ttype = num_types;     /*********** right here *******************/
        num_types++;
        type.push_back(n);
    }
```

explosionhandler passed as pointer to object rocket:

rocket.h:

```
...
class explosionhandler;
class rocket {
public:
        ...
        void setrocket(ALLEGRO_BITMAP*& a,ALLEGRO_BITMAP*& b, explosionhandler*& h);
        ...
        int exptype;
        ...
}; #endif
```

rocket.cpp:

```
rocket::rocket()
{
        ...
        exptype=-1;
}
void rocket::setrocket(ALLEGRO_BITMAP*& a,ALLEGRO_BITMAP*& b, explosionhandler*& h)
{
    handler = h;
    area.sethitboundaries(a);
    fprintf(stdout,"setrocket, # of rockets in vector: %i\n",(int)rockets.size());
h->registerexplosion(exptype,b,3,(float)al_get_bitmap_width(b),(float)0,(float)-18); //called function
}
```

and finally main.cpp (abbreviated):

```
#include "rocket.h"
#include "explosionhandler.h"
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define PI 3.14159265
...
rocket rock(bullet_speed+2,width,height);
explosionhandler *handler;
...
int setup()
{
        ...
        rock.setrocket(rk,exp,handler);
        rock.setlimit(5);
        al_set_target_bitmap(al_get_backbuffer(display));
        ...
}
...
```

Ok Yeah its clear now the problem was handler was not initialized. whoops.

and of course explosionhandler is a pointer in main.cpp, rocket is an object declared in main.cpp, both are globals.

Bless my little noob heart I know not what I do.

Comment: Can you please format your code so that it is readable?  It seems to have lost all indentation.

Comment: In addition to the indentation, it would also help to show the context from which you call `setrocket()`.  For example, I assume that the `rocket` object on which you call `setrocket()` is valid (but you should double-check that).  Also, when you call `setrocket()`, what are you passing for the `h` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic sense tells me that you're calling `rocket::setrocket` with a NULL pointer as the parameter `h` (or more specifically, a reference to a NULL pointer), and then you're calling `h->registerexplosion()` on the NULL pointer.

Don't do that.  Pass in a valid pointer instead, or allocate a new object (making sure you delete it properly later).

Comment: @jasondancks: It would be, "initialize your pointers, grandpa". Kids would be modern and not use naked pointers at all! :-)

Comment: Ouch. What so how would the youngsters do it? (I'm 22 :D)

Comment: Nah, with it's ownership rules `auto_ptr` is like the [OAG](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/overly-attached-girlfriend) of the smart pointer world. I would suggest [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). ;)